# Why is ASP.NET Remember Me Feature so Forgetful?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project using ASP.NET Identity 2.2. I set this up using the "Individual User Accounts" Authentication option in Visual Studio. I can login without issue. If I do not click Remember Me and close the browser after login, my credentials are not remembered on re-open. If I do click Remember Me and close the browser after login, my credentials are remembered on re-open. So far so good.

The problem comes when I click Remember Me, login, close the browser, and leave it closed for an extended period of time (my tests make me think it must be more than 20 minutes). When I do that, my credentials are forgotten and I have to login again. Why is this occurring?

When I open the browser up again after the 20 minutes, the AspNet.ApplicationCookie cookie is still present and has an expiration time that is about two weeks in the future.

I've seen other articles mention the UseCookieAuthentication method call, so I have included that below. I believe that I am using the defaults for this.

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Comment: 20 minutes is about how long it takes for an idle AppDomain to recycle. If you have a different account connecting to your page, to keep it from going idle, it might remember you for longer.

Comment: My web hosting provider does not allow me to modify the AppDomain idle timeout, so I setup a scheduled task to ping the web site periodically. After doing that, I am no longer seeing the issue. Feel free to add an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20 minutes is about how long it takes for an idle AppDomain to recycle. If you have a different account connecting to your page, to keep it from going idle, it might remember you for longer.